# Enable connection bar in FreeRDP

Tags: freerdp

Is there a way to enable the FreeRDP connection bar when in full screen mode? I am using FreeRDP version 1.1.1-hp16.3. I want to display the connection bar when the remote desktop is in full screen mode but I couldn't find any option to enable this feature in the settings. I have gone through some solutions on the internet and what I have found was executing a command by adding `/floatbar[:sticky:[on|off],default:[visible|hidden],show:[always|fullscreen||window]]`. So, I tried to run this command on terminal:

```
xfreerdp /v:192.168.10.124 /cert-ignore -authentication /f /floatbar:sticky:on,default:visible,show:fullscreen
```

Yet, I end up with this error.

```
Warning xf_GetWindowProperty (332): Properties 325 does not exist
Warning xf_GetWindowProperty (332): Properties 325 does not exist
Error: protocol security negotiation or connection failure
```

Anybody has idea with this?

Comment: Maybe it is authenticate problem. I use this command and there is no issue, floatbar is displayed at top
`xfreerdp /v:ip_address /u:username /p:password /f /floatbar:sticky:on,default:visible,show:fullscreen`